# Select! between Interval and UdpFramed next() blocks

Tags: rust, udp, rust-tokio

I am attempting to have a `tokio::select!` loop where I want an `Interval` to `tick()` every second and listen for Udp messages to come in on a `UdpFramed` `Stream`

When there are no messages, the `Interval` ticks just fine, but when a message is received, it seems like the loop is blocking on f.next() but I don't understand why.

Shouldn't `next()` call `poll_next()` on the `Stream` and only wait for the next item if it is available? And thus shouldn't it skip this `select!` arm and just keep on ticking?

```
use futures::StreamExt;
use socket2::{Domain, Protocol, SockAddr, Socket, Type};
use std::io;
use std::net::{Ipv4Addr, SocketAddrV4};
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::net::UdpSocket;
use tokio::select;
use tokio::time::interval;

use tokio_util::codec::BytesCodec;
use tokio_util::udp::UdpFramed;

//MULTICAST Constants
const IP_ANY: [u8; 4] = [0, 0, 0, 0];

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    pretty_env_logger::init();
    info!("Tokio Select Example");
//Create a udp ip4 socket
let socket = Socket::new(Domain::IPV4, Type::DGRAM, Some(Protocol::UDP))?;

//Allow this port to be reused by other sockets
socket.set_reuse_address(true)?;
socket.set_reuse_port(true)?;

//Create IPV4 any adress
let address = SocketAddrV4::new(IP_ANY.into(), 5353);

println!("Created Address");

//Bind to wildcard 0.0.0.0
socket.bind(&SockAddr::from(address))?;

println!("Bound Socket");

//Join multicast group
socket.join_multicast_v4(&Ipv4Addr::new(224, 0, 0, 251), address.ip())?;

println!("Joined Multicast");

//Convert to std::net udp socket
let udp_std_socket: std::net::UdpSocket = socket.into();

//Convert to tokio udp socket
let udp_socket = UdpSocket::from_std(udp_std_socket)?;

println!(
    "Created a UDP Socket at {}, {}",
    address.ip().to_string(),
    address.port().to_string()
);

let mut f = UdpFramed::new(udp_socket, BytesCodec::new());
let mut interval = interval(Duration::from_secs(1));

loop {
    select! {

        result = tokio::time::timeout(Duration::from_millis(200), f.next()) => {
            println!("{:?}", result);
        }
        default = interval.tick() => {
            println!("Tick!");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work. Please provide an example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: This could should reproduce the problem. When I run this and a message arrives, the loop does not keep running. I 'll add the rest of the sample code here

Comment: just ahead of me, see update :-)

Comment: Is the multicast code necessary? That example doesn't look very minimal to me. Also, I'd replace the `log`s with `println` for stackoverflow, they only add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Can't determine if the multicast has any influence on whether the Stream is blocking or not so I'll keep that in for this specific question. println! is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the documentation of [`UdpSocket::from_std()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.from_std):

> This function is intended to be used to wrap a UDP socket from the standard library in the Tokio equivalent. The conversion assumes nothing about the underlying socket; it is left up to the user to set it in non-blocking mode.

You are not setting the underlying socket in non-blocking mode.

This works:

```rust
use futures::StreamExt;
use socket2::{Domain, Protocol, SockAddr, Socket, Type};
use std::io;
use std::net::SocketAddrV4;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::net::UdpSocket;
use tokio::select;
use tokio::time::interval;

use tokio_util::codec::BytesCodec;
use tokio_util::udp::UdpFramed;

//MULTICAST Constants
const IP_ANY: [u8; 4] = [0, 0, 0, 0];

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    println!("Tokio Select Example");
    //Create a udp ip4 socket
    let socket = Socket::new(Domain::IPV4, Type::DGRAM, Some(Protocol::UDP))?;

    //Allow this port to be reused by other sockets
    socket.set_reuse_address(true)?;
    socket.set_reuse_port(true)?;
    socket.set_nonblocking(true)?;

    //Create IPV4 any adress
    let address = SocketAddrV4::new(IP_ANY.into(), 15253);
    println!("Created Address");

    //Bind to wildcard 0.0.0.0
    socket.bind(&SockAddr::from(address))?;
    println!("Bound Socket");

    //Convert to tokio udp socket
    let udp_socket = UdpSocket::from_std(socket.into())?;

    println!(
        "Created a UDP Socket at {}, {}",
        address.ip().to_string(),
        address.port().to_string()
    );

    let mut f = UdpFramed::new(udp_socket, BytesCodec::new());
    let mut interval = interval(Duration::from_secs(1));

    loop {
        println!("A");
        select! {
            result = tokio::time::timeout(Duration::from_millis(200), f.next()) => {
                println!("{:?}", result);
            }
            _ = interval.tick() => {
                println!("Tick!");
            }
        }
        println!("Z");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, was looking in the completely wrong place for the problem

Comment: Why aren't you using tokio sockets directly? I don't see the advantage of using an std socket first and then handing it over to tokio.

Comment: Right, so the reason I used the standard sockets is due to the setting of the REUSE_ADDR and PORT options due to the multicast resolver probably not being the only one using these parameters on the system, but for this question specifically  this does not matter :)